# How to test the program has quit? [JUnit]

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to build a simple app, which has a switch/case statement as follows:

```
    public void handleUserInput(char input){
      switch(input) {
        case 'L':
            printBooksList();
            break;
        case 'Q':
            System.exit(0);
        default:
            System.out.println("The option you chose was invalid");
      }
    }
```

I'm trying to do this TDD to learn some of the basics, with JUnit and Mockito. However I have absolutely no idea how to test a program has quit. I have to create an object of MyApp to then pass in a mocked InputStream with the value 'Q' quit, so somehow mocking doesn't fit. Even if this method was public, it's not exactly a method I can verify has been called through mocks.

Does anyone know any way on how to go about this?

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234526/java-writing-unittest-for-exiting-a-program-when-user-type-quit-in-the-console) but I'm not testing a static method, and having another constructor to pass in a mocked out System seems overkill.

This is the test I have written taking answers from the question I linked to:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldCallSystemExit() {
      inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("X".getBytes());
      testSubject = new BibliotecaApp(inputStream);
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);

      testSubject.handleUserInput('Q');

      PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
      System.exit(0);

      System.out.println("If this message displays them System.exit() was mocked successfully");
  }
```

But this is throwing dependency issues left right and centre! I've had to download 5 jars for PowerMock to work and it's still asking for hamcrest/SelfDescribing. This can't be right, I'll be downloading everything at this rate.

Comment: Brad's answer to that question is what you should be looking at.  You can use PowerMockito to mock `System.exit()`.

Comment: Including adding another constructor to be able to add my own System Exiter just for tests? That feels a bit dirty.

Comment: No, you don't need any of the extra method stuff from David Wallace's answer.  You just need to write a unit test the way Brad's answer shows, where you `PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);` and then run `handleUserInput()` (and then check to see if `System.exit()` was called).

Comment: I've done that and now it's asking me to download about 5+ jars for dependencies. This really seems overkill for such a small test, but I haven't worked with PowerMock before, so is this a tradeoff that it comes with? I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I agree on the overkill front, but PowerMockito is the only way I've heard of that lets you test a static method like `System.exit()`.  The only other way I can think of to handle this would be rather than calling exit directly, to isntead invoke a general clean-up task (which you would then have to mock normally). But that adds a bunch of un-needed complexity to the production code.  I'd rather have the mess in my test code... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to test `System.exit()` in a JUnit test:

1. Mock it with [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/)
2. Call a method which calls `System.exit()` and overwrite this method in the test.
3. Use the [System Rules library](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/index.html#ExpectedSystemExit) (kudos go to Stefan Birkner for pointing that out)

The reason is that `System.exit()` never returns, so control never returns to your test. So you have to make sure that the actual method isn't called.

Comment: Another way is to use the System Rules library: http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/index.html#ExpectedSystemExit